# What will be the output of the pseudocode below and why?

Tags: arrays, arraylist, pseudocode

The answer for all three situations is supposedly 3, i dont understand why that is, can someone please explain what is going on and the reasoning behind it, why is the answer 3 for all situations ?

I am new to code, a beginner and need help.

Here is the code

```
Z [],  T = Z[1]  Z.SIZE>1   T = T+Z[Z.SIZE]  T

What does this process out in the following situations ?
Z[] = [1,2]
Z[] = [1,2,3]
Z[] = [3]
```

I dont understand the result of the array, i dont understand the logic behind it. I need a simple and easy to understand explanation of the results.

Comment: What kind of pseudocode is that? It looks like you have omitted essential parts from it?

Answer (score 0):

That pseudocode looks unusual: all the code is presented on the same line (bad!), no keywords like `if` or `while` or `for`... No clear indication what part is conditional, and what is not. This is atypical in honestly does not pass the standard of what pseudocode is supposed to look like.

I will have a guess at what this code means:

```
Z [],  T = Z[1]  Z.SIZE>1   T = T+Z[Z.SIZE]  T
```

...rewriting it in propper pseudocode:

```
function calculate(Z[1..Z.SIZE]):
    T ← Z[1]
    if Z.SIZE > 1 then:
        T ← T + Z[Z.SIZE]
    return T
```

This function takes the first element of `Z` and the last element of `Z` (if `Z` has more than one element), and returns the sum of these.

So then we have these expected outputs:

- calling the function with argument `Z = [1,2]` will result in 3
- calling the function with argument `Z = [1,2,3]` will result in 4
- calling the function with argument `Z = [3]` will result in 3